# Lua. Поиск по таблице

Tags: lua

У меня есть таблица которая получается при помощи парсинга - например:
table = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5}

А так же таблица с необходимыми мне данными:
i_need = {'1','3','5'}

Как сделать так, что бы скрипт считывал первую таблицу и сверял по второй, есть ли такой элемент в списке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```lua
local i_have = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
local i_need = {1, 3, 5}

for _, value_i_have in ipairs(i_have) do
  for _, value_i_need in ipairs(i_need) do
    if value_i_need == value_i_have then print(value_i_need) end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
table = {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'}
i_need = {'1','3','5'}
for i=1, #table do
    for ii = 1, #i_need do
        if table[i] == i_need[ii] then
            print(table[i])
        end
    end
end
```